# bottle: use jinja2_view decorator

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle, python-decorators

If I import post, get, and jinja2_view directly from bottle, I'm able to use a jinja2_view as a decorator:

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, jinja2_view

@jinja2_view('index.html')
@get('/')
def index():
    return

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

But if I import and use the `Bottle()` constructor, I can no longer use the jinja decorator:

```
from bottle import Bottle, get, post, request, run, jinja2_view

app = Bottle()

@app.jinja2_view('index.html')
@app.get('/')
def index():
    return

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    @app.jinja2_view('index.html')
AttributeError: 'Bottle' object has no attribute 'jinja2_view'
```

How can I use jinja2_view with the `Bottle()` constructor? (the constructor is necessary because I'm using a mysql lib that requires `app.install(plugin)`.

## EDIT 1

If I use `@app.get()` together with `@jinja2_view` the callback function doesn't have access to the plugin

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, jinja2_view, Bottle

import bottle_mysql

app = Bottle()
plugin = bottle_mysql.Plugin(dbuser='bottle',dbpass='password', dbname='mydb')
app.install(plugin)

@app.get('/now')
@jinja2_view('now.html')
def get_now(db):
    db.execute('SELECT now() as now')
    row = db.fetchone()
    now = str(row['now'])
    return { 'now': now }

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

Exception:

```
TypeError('get_now() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)',)
```

If I comment out `@jinja2_view('now.html')` the route works and returns the correct json response.

Comment: Please see the comment below my answer regarding your edit.

Answer (score 2):

`jinja2_view` is a function provided by the bottle module, it is not a class method of the `Bottle` class.
Therefore, when you call `@app.jinja2_view`, python searchs `app` (which is an instance of `bottle.Bottle`) for an attribute called jinja2_view, which it obviously fails to find.

So, you have two really easy options to correct this:

1. You can go back to using `@jinja2_view('index.html')`.
2. Just import bottle and use fully qualified namespacing for all the bottle methods, e.g. `@bottle.jinja2_view('index.html')` and `app = bottle.Bottle()`.

I personally have a strong preference for the latter, as it avoids accidental pollution of the global namespace, which can be important as these small projects build around webservers tend to grow and bloat over time. Of course, your mileage may vary.

### Edit

I've created an even simpler example based off your original, hopefully this will help determine where the problem lies. Try running this:

```
from bottle import get, run, jinja2_view, Bottle
import datetime

app = Bottle()
@app.get('/now')
@jinja2_view('now.html')
def get_now():
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return { 'now': now }

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Viewing this in the browser renders the datetime string correctly within an `<h1>` element. If it works for you as well, the problem may lie with the plugin.

Comment: I added a snippet to show why this doesn't work in edit 1

Comment: That's because in your snippet you've placed the `jinja2_view` decorator below the route decorator. The route decorator should be the last thing before the route handler def. Just reverse their ordering and your example should work.

Comment: when I reverse the order, the jinja2 template isn't rendered. It's ignored and I get a blank screen.

Comment: Can you show me what your `now.html` template looks like?

Comment: `<h1>{{now}}</h1>`

Comment: @sheepdog try running the code I added in my edit and see if you have any issues with it.

Comment: That works, but it won't work with the `bottle-mysql` lib.  I ended up dropping `bottle-mysql` and using http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html instead.  Then I was able to create the db cursor object at the top of the file and access it inside the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because, as the error says, the [`Bottle`](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#the-bottle-class) class has no attribute `jinja2_view`. But thre's no problem if you use them both, each for its purpose: `Bottle()` to instantiate your app and `jinja2_view` to render template.

Comment: I added a snippet to show why this doesn't work in edit 1